# Python Serial communication Arduino (Teensy) to Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have managed it to write from my arduino (Uno) to my Raspberry Pi 3 via Serial.

If I use the same python script on the pi side, and the same Sketch on arduino side, **but using a Teensy** instead, I cant read any output from my Arduino.

Is there any difference between thes arduino Uno and the teensy depending on Serial communication?

Arduino sketch:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("10.7;0.7;FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:");
}
```

Python script on my Pi:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0",115200)
while True:
    print("Waiting for messages from arduino..");
    read_ser=ser.readline()
    print(read_ser)
```

This code works fine for my Arduino Uno, but not for my Teensy.
**ttyACM0** is correct in both cases.

OS on the Pi is ubuntu mate 16.04.
I can see the output of both arduinos in the Arduino IDE.

I tried this with 3 different Teensies, so the hardware should not be the problem.

Any advices?

** `ser.isOpen()` is true

`bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting() print(ser.read(bytesToRead))` makes no difference.

Could there be a difference, because the teensy is connected with the pi with micro usb, and the UNO is connected with an [A to B USB](http://www.skyviewelectronics.com/sites/skyviewelectronics.com/files/usb-a-to-b-cable.jpg)?

Comment: remove this line: `ser.baudrate=115200`

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the advice but this makes do difference.

Comment: execute `print(ser.isOpen())` inside the loop.

Comment: @eyllanesc it is open, I also get an error if I remove the USB from my pi, while the scrpt is running ** It doesnt pass readline(), it hangs there

Comment: Change while loop to `bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
    print(ser.read(bytesToRead))`

Comment: @eyllanesc also no difference :/

Comment: Could there be a difference, because the teensy is connected with the pi with micro usb, and the UNO is connected with an A to B USB? (this one) http://www.skyviewelectronics.com/sites/skyviewelectronics.com/files/usb-a-to-b-cable.jpg

Comment: **You can't read data on `teensy` if haven't an hardware opening procedure** Probable missing points : `handshake`, `additional data for open bus`. Dump bus data and you will be see `python` and `terminal` data different.

Comment: Arduino have low speed `usb-ser` but `teensy(3.X)` got `6Mb/s`(i tested) bus. Some high speed devices required additional data before start a communication.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you know my next steps should be, It would be really nice if you could answer my question, so I can mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @dsgdfg You also know that i want to write from teensy to computer, not read? just to be sure :)

Comment: Don't do this @MoritzSchmidt , unidirectional communication most awful things on communicate with a device. On `teensy` speed definition `Serial.begin(115200);` or `Serial.begin(0);` or `Serial.begin(12345678);` not important because got `12Mb/s` connection if used native port.

Comment: So there is no solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teensy is an **ACM** device ? **YES !**

Got additional **BULK IN** and **BULK OUT** `ENDPOINTS`(Interrupt_dev = 0, CDC_dev=1)

[image: ACM device]

Your `Teensy` code is very bad (**Why calculate and send data if don't need ?**)!

For test program like this :

```
unsigned long s = 0;
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(0);//Not important !(speed 12Mb/s)
    }

void loop(){
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
    while(Serial.available() > 0){//Buffer memory must always be clean !
        char read = Serial.read();
        delay(1);//wait until next_char
        }
    Serial.print("TEST : ");
    Serial.println(s, DEC);
    s++;
    }
}
```

Python Code :

```
import thread
import time
time.sleep(20)
#Don't fight with the Kernel, wait some seconds for prepare device

class _CDC :
    def __init__(self):
        self.dev = "/dev/ttyACM0"
        self.query = ""
    def read(self,_passarg):
        with open("/dev/ttyACM0","r") as readBuff:
            while True :
                ans = readBuff.readline()
                if ans:
                    print ans[:-2]#Ignore "\r\n" parts ! 
                #time sleep for save cpu clocks
                time.sleep(0.001)
    def write(self,_passarg):
        with open("/dev/ttyACM0","a") as writeBuff:
            while True :
                if self.query != "" :
                    writeBuff.write(self.query+"\n")
                    self.query = ""
                #time sleep for save cpu clocks
                time.sleep(0.001)

CDC = _CDC()
thread.start_new_thread(CDC.read,(None,))
thread.start_new_thread(CDC.write,(None,))

for i in range(30):
    q = "SEND-TEST%02d"%i
    CDC.query = q+((64-len(q))*"\x00")
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Can read write (like a file object) if device is `ACM`. Open device with "r" and "a" mode for reading last-line.

Comment: I am also having trouble reading and writing to a Teensy from a Raspberry Pi. Can you give an example of using the class _CDC? I am confused by your code. What is the arg _passarg for in read and write? Can you give an example of reading and writing like a file?